# Calculating length of line using British National Grid projection?

Tags: length

I need to calculate the length of a line in (KM) in QGIS using the British National Grid as the Projection.

Can somebody explain to me how to do this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This question isn't an exact duplicate of "Finding line length while editing in QGIS", but the answers to that question also answer this one.

Comment: OSGB is in meters. so sum up the lengths and divide by 1000 for km.